# Dynamically setAttribute of multiple choice select box with each choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, bootstrap-select

I have a few multiple choice select boxes within my form, and to make them look nice I'm using bootstrap select. As the core of this app is developed in Express, I can't grab the values the user selects because bootstrap select makes a div and a list that the user is actually interacting with. To solve this I'm trying to write some javascript/jquery to add the selected=true to each option that is selected. I figured that out, but then realized that if I were to deselect an option, it still shows as selected=true.

I've tried using `$(this).find("option:not(:selected)").get(i).setAttribute('selected', false);`
However this throw an error after making multiple selections.

HTML

```
 <label for="performThese">I will perform</label>
 <select class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" multiple id="performThese" name="performThese" data-style="btn-secondary" title="Choose your option..">
   <option value="residential_BPO">Residential BPOs</option>
   <option value="commercial_valuation">Commercial Property Valuations</option>
   <option value="condition_report">Property Detail & Condition Reports</option>
  </select>
```

Javscript

```
$(function() {
 // Style only selects with the selectpicker class
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
 // Get the target multiple select box for testing
let selectTarget = document.getElementsByName('performThese');
 // Wait for a change
$(selectTarget).on('change', function(e){
 // How many options selected?
let selectTargetLength = $(this).find("option:selected").length;
 // Make a blank array
let selectValue = [];
let i = 0;
while (i < selectTargetLength) {
 // Grab value of each choosen option in case needed for evaluation
  selectValue[i] = $(this).find("option:selected").get(i).value;
// Make options choose show as selected
  $(this).find("option:selected").get(i).setAttribute('selected', true);
  i++
}
});
})
```

I expected selected=true to dissapear when I've deselected an entry.

Comment: Are you sure that the selectpicker does not set the selected value back on the element that it was initialized from?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. I've tried everything under the sun to allow it too. jquery is loaded first, and they are initialized only after the DOM is ready. 
Scripts are loaded in the footer as
   jquery, popper, bootstrap, bootstrap-select 
In that order. It initializes correctly, and I get no errors

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place? That attribute isn't really relevant after page loads. The values themselves are also available in the plugin API  as are events for changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
 // Style only selects with the selectpicker class
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
 // Get the target multiple select box for testing
let selectTarget = document.getElementsByName('performThese');
 // Wait for a change
$(selectTarget).on('change', function(e){

    //firstly clean all options:
    $(this).find("option").attr("selected", false);

    //selected options are still available with find("option:selected")

    //marks all selected options:
    $(this).find("option:selected").attr("selected",true);

});
})
```